# Bug no Safari de uma animação CSS com keyframes

Tags: css, css3, scss

No safari Versão 12.1 (14607.1.40.1.4), ocorre um bug, o efeito acontece, porém dá um erro estranho, o elemento que sofreu o evento parece retroceder, a posição inicial do **translate3d**, diferente do chrome, que realmente mantém o elemento na nova posição da nova posição do **translate3d**.

```
 ul.tools.finish-animation {
        display: block;
        animation: downBumble 700ms;
        -moz-animation: downBumble 700ms; /* Firefox */
        -webkit-animation: downBumble 700ms; /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-animation: downBumble 700ms; /* Opera */
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        will-change: transform;

      }


@keyframes downBumble {
  20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -90px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -30px, 0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -30px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -30px, 0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -15px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -15px, 0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }

}
@-moz-keyframes downBumble { /* Firefox */
  20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -90px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -30px, 0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -30px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -30px, 0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -15px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -15px, 0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }

}
@-webkit-keyframes downBumble { /* Safari and Chrome */
  20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -90px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -30px, 0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -30px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -30px, 0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -15px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -15px, 0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }


}
@-o-keyframes downBumble { /* Opera */
  20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -90px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -30px, 0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -30px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -30px, 0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -15px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -15px, 0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }

}
```

[**Fiddle de exemplo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/e2oLpjy6/)

Comment: Não sei se vai resolver, mas coloque um valor final na animação nos 100%, tipo `100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  }` e se vc quer que a animação só se repita 1x coloque o `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;` pode ser que ajude tb. Testa ai e me fala, aqui não tenho um ambiente com Safari par poder testar ... Outra opção tb é testar trocando `translate3d` por `translateY(30px) etc` já iqe vc só movimenta o elemento no eixo Y ele já é o suficiente

Comment: [Coloquei](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/7fmzt869/1/), mesmo assim, não rolou... :(

Comment: Como não consigo debugar no safari, acho que nessa não consigo ajudar muito... mas vou "refazer" essa animação com um CSS mais limpo e te passo pra vc testar.

Comment: Ivan testa ai pra ver se o bug continua. Outra coisa, segundo o CanIUse vc nem precisa escrever o vendor prefix `-webkit-` para `transform` ou `animation`, então segue a versão simplificada. Eu dei uma boa limpada no CSS e a animação ficou muito similar https://codepen.io/hugocsl/pen/bXwbaJ

Comment: Resolveu aqui, valeu!

Comment: Ivan resolveu com a dica ou resolveu de outra forma? Se foi com o código posso postar como resposta?

Comment: Pode sim, vc limpou o código como no seu exemplo do codepen e funcionou, valeu! Acho que o problema é que estava tendo era esse 700ms no início da classe, que não precisava.

Comment: Alguma coisa que eu tirei estava buggando rss, esses 700ms era o tempo de execução, não sei se estava relacionado a ele. Mas com esse modelo mais simples que fiz, fica até melhor para vc dar manutenção no código, além de ter resolvido o problema :). Valeu a força 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme conversado nos comentários da pergunta segue a resposta.

O Safari 12, conforme pode ser consultado no [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/), não precisa mais dos prefixos `-webkit-` nas animações, keyframes ou transition. Outro ponte é que como a animação é apenas no eixo `Y`, não precisa usar o `translate3d` nem `preserve-3d` entre outras coisas que estavam no CSS e mais pesavam na animação do que ajudavam em alguma coisa.

Partindo dessas observações, dei essa "limpa" no CSS e ajustei os timings da da animação e parece funcionar no Safari sem problemas.

```css
ul.tools li {
  float: left;
  padding: 6px;
  list-style:none;
  font-family: sans-serif;

  animation: anima 350ms linear forwards;
}

@keyframes anima {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  50%{
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="tools finish-animation">
  <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>         
</ul>
```